Could not load file assembly 'System.Resources.ResourceManager, Version=4.0.0.0' after upgrade System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe to 6.0.0
My ASP.NET MVC Project target 4.8.
The IIS could not load file or assembly 'System.Resources.ResourceManager, Version=4.0.0.0' after upgrade System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe from 4.7.1 to version to 6.0.0.
enter image description here
I try upgrade Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="4.1.0" to fix the problem but do not successful.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException means the program did not find the file you specified. Try to installed and update System.Resources.ResourceManager in the project and other class libraries also.

@awla shuang I try  install System.Resources.ResourceManager (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Resources.ResourceManager/) but It does not solve the problem.

Use the Process Monitor to monitor  DLL activity in real-time. and this case may help you
